# Catch invalid variable name with SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

First off the catch clause isn't being executed. But I am getting "SyntaxError: missing exponent" error in the browser. I'm wondering if it's because of load time? Or my setup is not right.

I want to make a custom error for incorrect variable name.

```
try {
  var 1ele = 1;
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceOf SyntaxError) {
    throw new SyntaxError("There is a syntax error!");
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are getting a syntax error. `catch` catches runtime errors. (Don't try to catch syntax errors unless if you are doing `eval`s.) 2 more things... DONT start your variable with a number and your variable is having the exponet error because it is reading `1e` and thinking it is an exponent with the exponent following the e.

Comment: @pepperjack—mostly good, but `var 1ele` is a straight syntax error: `var ` must be followed by a valid identifier, which can't start with a number so fails at the `1`, the parser doesn't get any further. ;-)

Comment: @RobG as he said, his syntax error is `SyntaxError: missing exponent`. It does reach it in his case. You aren't wrong, there is a syntax error with the variable, but for his browser it stopped (or at least threw) at the error stated above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but that's not a valid js variable name.

Comment: @pepperjack—weird, there's no reason to do that, shows the vagaries of parsers. Chrome gives "Invalid or unexpected token", which is expected (and IE gives "Expected identifier").

Comment: @RobG Just another example of how javascript is a bad scripting language... I honestly wish we could've gotten something better that is less async and open as JS is.

Comment: @pepperjack—I don't think it's anything to do with the language *per se*, but with how parsers/compilers are optimised. For such a crappy language it's done pretty well for itself. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Well, compilers and parsers have to be extremely flexible which causes stuff like this to happen when it comes to javascript. I mean, take a look at this: https://pastebin.com/KmM1bN2w both are valid, take a stroll on the internet and you'll see this crazy stuff (at least for a C-strict type person like me) everywhere: https://charlieharvey.org.uk/page/javascript_the_weird_parts

Comment: @pepperjack—horses for courses, look a the history. Javascript started over 20 years ago as a simple scripting language for HTML authors. Now it's trying to be a full–blown programming language so that any other language can compile into javascript. Delusions of grandeur? Maybe, but what started as a small, simple language written in 10 days has now been extended and bastardised beyond recognition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have introduced a Syntax error in your code `var 1ele = 1;` and intend to catch the error to display a custom error message. However this won't work in the way you have written now since the Syntax error will cause the JavaScript parser to stop soon after encountering the Syntax error. The `catch` part of your code will never be reached.

However, you can implement the same using an `eval` statement. Try the code below.

```js
try {
  eval("var 1ele = 1");
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {
    throw new SyntaxError("There is a syntax error!");
  }
}
```

Here, I have wrapped the Syntax error causing variable declaration inside an `eval` function. This will cause the syntax error only in the environment where the `eval` statement is executed and not your main code. You will be able to catch the error and display your custom message.

*NOTE 1:* You are getting the `"SyntaxError: missing exponent"` error message because your variable name starts with `1e` which makes the JavaScript parser think that it is a number in exponential format.

*NOTE 2:* You have used `instanceOf` in your code. It is actually `instanceof` (with a lower case `o`). [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)